# pytorch freeze weights and update param_groups

Tags: python, machine-learning, computer-vision, pytorch

Freezing weights in pytorch for `param_groups` setting.

So if one wants to freeze weights during training:

```
for param in child.parameters():
    param.requires_grad = False
```

the optimizer also has to be updated to not include the non gradient weights:

```
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(filter(lambda p: p.requires_grad, model.parameters()), lr=opt.lr, amsgrad=True)
```

If one wants to use different `weight_decay` / learning rates for bias and weights/this also allows for differing learning rates:

```
param_groups = [{'params': model.module.bias_parameters(), 'weight_decay': args.bias_decay},
                {'params': model.module.weight_parameters(), 'weight_decay': args.weight_decay}]
```

`param_groups` a *list* of *dics* is defined and passed into `SGD` as follows:

```
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(param_groups, args.lr,
                                 betas=(args.momentum, args.beta))
```

**How can this be achieved with freezing individual weights**? Running filter over a list of dics or is there a way of adding tensors to the optimizer separately?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Actually I think you don't have to update the `optimizer`. The `Parameters` handed over to the `optimizer` are just references.

So when you change the `requires_grad` flag it will immediately be updated.

But even if that would for some reason not be the case - as soon as you you set the `requires_grad` flag to be `False` you cannot anymore calculate gradients any ***new gradients*** (see at the bottom with `None` and zero gradients) for this weight, so the gradient won't change anymore and if you use `optimizer.zero_grad()` it will just stay `zero`.

So if there is no gradient, then there is also no need to exclude these from the `optimizer`. Because without gradient the `optimizer` will just do nothing, no matter what learning rate you use.

Here is an small example to show this behaviour:

```py
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.optim as optim

n_dim = 5

p1 = nn.Linear(n_dim, 1)
p2 = nn.Linear(n_dim, 1)

optimizer = optim.Adam(list(p1.parameters())+list(p2.parameters()))
p2.weight.requires_grad = False
for i in range(4):
    dummy_loss = (p1(torch.rand(n_dim)) + p2(torch.rand(n_dim))).squeeze()
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    dummy_loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()
    print('p1: requires_grad =', p1.weight.requires_grad, ', gradient:', p1.weight.grad)
    print('p2: requires_grad =', p2.weight.requires_grad, ', gradient:', p2.weight.grad)
    print()

    if i == 1:
        p1.weight.requires_grad = False
        p2.weight.requires_grad = True
```

Output:

```py
p1: requires_grad = True , gradient: tensor([[0.8522, 0.0020, 0.1092, 0.8167, 0.2144]])
p2: requires_grad = False , gradient: None

p1: requires_grad = True , gradient: tensor([[0.7635, 0.0652, 0.0902, 0.8549, 0.6273]])
p2: requires_grad = False , gradient: None

p1: requires_grad = False , gradient: tensor([[0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]])
p2: requires_grad = True , gradient: tensor([[0.1343, 0.1323, 0.9590, 0.9937, 0.2270]])

p1: requires_grad = False , gradient: tensor([[0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]])
p2: requires_grad = True , gradient: tensor([[0.0100, 0.0123, 0.8054, 0.9976, 0.6397]])
```

Here you can see that no gradients are calculated. You may have notice the gradient for `p2` is `None` at the beginning and later on it is `tensor([[0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]])` for `p1` instead of `None` after deactivating gradients.

This is the case because `p1.weight.grad` is just a variable which is modified by `backward()` and `optimizer.zero_grad()`.

So at the beginning `p1.weight.grad` is just initialized with `None`, after the gradients are written or accumulated to this variable they won't be cleared automatically. But because `optimizer.zero_grad()` is called they are set to zero and stay like this since `backward()` cannot anymore calculate new gradients with `requires_grad=False`.

You can also change the code in the `if`-statement to:

```py
if i == 1:
    p1.weight.requires_grad = False
    p1.weight.grad = None
    p2.weight.requires_grad = True
```

So once reset to `None` they are left untouched and stay `None`:

```py
p1: requires_grad = True , gradient: tensor([[0.2375, 0.7528, 0.1501, 0.3516, 0.3470]])
p2: requires_grad = False , gradient: None

p1: requires_grad = True , gradient: tensor([[0.5181, 0.5178, 0.6590, 0.6950, 0.2743]])
p2: requires_grad = False , gradient: None

p1: requires_grad = False , gradient: None
p2: requires_grad = True , gradient: tensor([[0.4797, 0.7203, 0.2284, 0.9045, 0.6671]])

p1: requires_grad = False , gradient: None
p2: requires_grad = True , gradient: tensor([[0.8344, 0.1245, 0.0295, 0.2968, 0.8816]])
```

I hope this makes sense to you!

Comment: Makes sense, although is there additional overhead by having the tensors in the computational graph yet not optimizing them?

Comment: @BenedictK. They are not added to the graph if `requires_grad` is `False`. This flag actually adds them to the graph. Meaning, for tensors with `requires_grad=True`, autograd keeps track of what calculations are done etc. these informations are saved in buffers. But with `requires_grad=False`  these informations won't be added to the graph. Quote: *"it’s enough to switch the `requires_grad` flags in the frozen base, and no intermediate buffers will be saved"* - That is what this flag is actually for, you can take a look here: https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/notes/autograd.html#requires-grad

Comment: This sentence from the [above linked site of the PyTorch-Documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/notes/autograd.html#autograd-mechanics) states it even more clear: *"Every Tensor has a flag: `requires_grad` that allows for fine grained exclusion of subgraphs from gradient computation and can increase efficiency."*

Comment: One more thing I that came to my mind what might explain it better: The *optimizer* itself actually has nothing to do with the *graph*. It just uses the already computed *graph* to alter the weights. So what whatever you put in the *optimizer* will not change the *graph*. But you can control the *graph* by setting the `requires_grad` flag accordingly to include or exclude certain calculations from the graph.

Comment: @blue-phoenox So if an intermediate entity was set with `requires_grad=False`, it would calculate a temporary grad value without actually strong it. That would explain how preceding layers manage to get a `grad` value.